# SQL View Performance increases after adding OR condition in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-performance

I have a view like this, which takes about 2 minutes to execute.

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4, ..., 
from table1 
inner join table2 on condition1
inner join table3 on condition2
inner join table4 on condition3
....
left outer join table12 on condition11
left outer join table13 on condition12
...
where condition13 and condition14 and condition15
```

but If I add an `OR` condition to the view, the performance increases dramatically, it takes about 13 sec. The `OR` condition will never be true in this case. `col1` is the primary key on the `table2`, any idea why would this happen, and is there a neat way to achieve these results.

```
OR table2.col1 = 0
```

Altered query:

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4, ..., 
from table1 
inner join table2 on condition1
inner join table3 on condition2
inner join table4 on condition3
....
left outer join table12 on condition11
left outer join table13 on condition12
...
where condition13 and condition14 and condition15 OR table2.col1 = 0
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried checking the execution plans of both versions? This could be the result of some out-of-date statistics, and the addition of the supposed-no-op `OR` condition could modify which indexes get used, or how.

Comment: What is the original query, and the altered query? It is unclear from your question whether the filter is on a `JOIN` or a `WHERE`. Also, posting the execution plans of both queries would help in determining why one query is faster than the other.

Comment: Updated the question now

Comment: I have compared the execution plan, the Index seek cost, Index scan and Key look up cost are less compared to original query

Comment: This seems to me like a case of parameter sniffing issue. Can you post the execution plans for both queries?

Comment: Sorry, Its huge I am not sure how to post it

Comment: Pretty impossible to say without the execution plans. Outside parameter sniffing which is a good bet, chances are the OR can cause the query to use other indexes or possible skip comparisons by being able to optimize them differently.

Comment: I've been running in similar issues lately. I had like you lots of inner joins and left joins and or's int the query. My execution plan was huge like yours. I guess the query was too complex to be optimized properly optimized by SQLServer (or my skills aren't good enough). In my case I ended up doing 2 querys and sorted the rest out in c#. That was way faster than any query I wrote/optimized. I don't know if that's an option for you.

Comment: @user2994641:try searching for brentozar paste the plan and paste the link here

Answer (score 0):

I've devised two simple POCs:

- `Case A`, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d0c53/1, with a straight forward `inner join` with a filter
- `Case B`, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d0c53/5, with the same `inner join` with the same filter plus an `ORed` condition yielding no extra results

Please, inspect the execution plan for both cases, clicking the link *View Execution Plan*.

Whereas for `Case A` there's a nested loop (with a **non-clustered** Index Seek), for `Case B` there's a potentially less time consuming merge join (although for sure more buffer space demanding).

Same result set, very different execution plans.

What these cases show us, considering your question? Well, sorry, nothing but bullocks.

I tried to demonstrate here that a single tweak in the query yield a completely different behaviour from the SQL Server Engine.

Even more, not shown here: the accuracy and freshness of the statistics have even greater weight for the engine plans — suddenly a fast query may turn into sluggish just because of changes on the statistics, not on the data, neither on the query itself.

Since you gave us no actual data and queries, you have to investigate yourself the atual query plans to devise why the two queries behave so differently.

And, welcome to this wonderful world of query tuning! Hope you enjoy it.